# Calling MS Dynamics CRM SOAP Service using Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, dynamics-crm-2011, soap-client, microsoft-dynamics

I am developing an ionic application which will interact with MS Dynamics CRM. I have looked online for solutions, but all solutions are either RESTful implementations or non MS Dynamics implementations. Has anyone implemented SOAP services of MS Dynamics using Angular JS? If possible please share example.

Comment: Have you looked at https://github.com/andrewmcgivery/angular-soap

Answer (score 1):

Several questions that probably will lead you to solution:

- Do you have special requirements to use `SOAP`? Most of CRM functionality successfully exposed via `REST` / `OData` endpoints. Only for really none-trivial cases you would need to use `SOAP` syntax. You can check list of current limitations [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt628816.aspx). Consider using `REST` instead.
- Another question would be, where your application is deployed? Is it within CRM itself? Or not? If Angular application is started within CRM (as WebResource) this is a lot simpler! Since you are already authorized to the service and you don't need to bother about that. In this case maybe [this library](https://github.com/SimplerSoftware/XrmTSToolkit) could provide you some help... there are several approaches to create great middleware for SOAP requests to CRM, this seems to be most modern one.
- But if you're not authorized... This is whole new level of the problem... Which environment you're targeting? OnLine? OnPrem?

In that case, first you need to authorize, then you can proceed with your queries, for example with the help of the library on previous step. There is one JS library that could help. It is abandoned, but you can take a look on the code. I'm talking about [dynamicscrm-api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dynamicscrm-api). It won't work in browser, but it will give you understanding, how you can move on.